# How do I get help within Python for an installed module?

Tags: python

How can I get help within Python on a function or method of an installed module?

Comment: -1 as you only need to type two words in your search engine or start a python shell to get an answer. You could start learning python by reading the [tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html)

Answer (score 4):

You can always try `help(your_function)` in the Python shell. This will print the documentation (`docstring` in Python lingo) of the corresponding function/class/package/... you're interested in.

If you're using [IPython](http://ipython.org/), you can also use `your_function?`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bpython](http://bpython-interpreter.org), which has inline help like this:

[image: inline help]

Answer (score 0):

To find the list of function in the module you can use

```
dir()
EX:
 import os
 dir(os)
```

And to access the docs of the module you can do

```
 os.__doc__
```